# how to upgrade 3.2.x wordpress to 4.x

Tags: wordpress

I have a client that has neglected to perform any Wordpress updates. They are on 3.2.1 using 2010 theme. I wan to get them updated to some version of 4 or possible stair step them. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Before you proceed take a backup of the root folder and export the database.
You can follow the steps in "Upgrading Across Multiple Versions".
https://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress_-_Extended_Instructions